# Encoding when read from a .txt file

Tags: python, utf-8

I am trying to extracting text under a section from txt file. I got â€™ instead of apostrophe ' when encoding is not identified. When I use encoding = 'utf-8', I got error message 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 669-670: invalid continuation byte. I assume it is due to issues in other parts of the txt file. I tried other options such as encoding='latin-1' and encoding = 'ISO-8859-1', then I got â\x80\x99 instead of apostrophe '

Any ideas on what encoding I should use? Here is the [Link](https://documents1.worldbank.org/curated/en/150451474555312380/text/000020051-20140625223916.txt) to the txt file.

```
mylines = []
with open('icrr.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as myfile:
   copy = False
   for line in myfile:
      if line.strip().lower().startswith("13. lessons"):
          copy = True
          continue
      elif line.strip().lower().startswith("14. assessment recommended"):
          copy = False
          continue
      elif copy:
          mylines.append(line)
print("".join(mylines))
```

---

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 669-670: invalid continuation byte

Comment: That file starts with a UTF-8 byte-order mark.  It's definitely UTF-8.  Your error doesn't make any sense; there are no non-ASCII characters until byte 5,392.  EXACTLY where did you put `encoding='utf-8'`?

Comment: I added encoding part to the code and the error message.

Answer (score 4):

The error is correct.  That file contains an invalid UTF-8 sequence at byte 17,053 (`E2 80 3F`).  It has been damaged somehow.

You can read this by telling Python to replace bad characters with '?':

```
with open('icrr.txt','r',encoding='utf-8',errors='replace'):
```